# Encrypt in VBScript/ASP Classic, Decrypt in PHP?

Tags: php, asp-classic, vbscript, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt a string in VBScript, and decrypt it in PHP.  I have full control over the VBScript/ASP Classic environment, but zero control over my PHP environment.

Given this, what sort of encryption could I use that would be adequate enough to secure a string?  Apologies for the vagueness of the question, but I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should try is simply using a standard encryption/decryption algorithm.

The problem is that these are handled by the php mcrypt extension and you may or may not have then available.

You want [mdecrypt_generic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php). But you can test for it with:

```
<?php

if(function_exists('mdecrypt_generic')){
      echo "Fred says 'you are going to be OK!'";
}else{
      echo "Fred says 'it is a shame you cannot control your php environment'";
}

?>
```

If it exists then plain text that you encrypt with the same algorithm and parameters on VBScript/ASP should decrypt on PHP just fine. Be prepared to try different algorithms if you get funny results, sometime a "parameter" can really mess with you...  If you do not have mcrypt then check for openssl. [openssl_seal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php) can do the same work for you, but you need to mess with x509 keys in that case. (I like [CACert.org](http://cacert.org) for simple x509 outsourcing...)

The other thing to consider... do you really need encryption or merely [obfuscation](https://www.php.net/base64_decode)?

HTH,

-FT

Comment: I need encryption, not obfuscation.  While this does not entirely answer my needs, it was helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is making its way between the servers via http then use https to send the string.  That way you don't have to do the encryption/decryption, thats done for you by SSL.