# Encode in ASP and decode in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, asp-classic

I am looking for 2 lines of code, one which will encrypt (using a shared key) a string in ASP and the other will decode the same string in PHP.

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Which type of algorithm? Are you encrypting, if so is it just public key or symmetric and which one? Which version of .NET and PHP? What modules for encryption do you have compiled into your php?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473186/encrypt-in-vbscript-asp-classic-decrypt-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard APIs, I doubt it will be possible to do in two lines. So if "two lines" is a strict requirement, I recommend starting an external process. Make sure you have openssl installed on both systems, and use the 'openssl enc' command.

To encrypt, do

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -k PASSWORD -in /tmp/infile -out /tmp/encrypted
```

To decrypt, do

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -k PASSWORD -in /tmp/encrypted -out /tmp/decrypted
```

Comment: 2 lines is not a requirement, but I was hoping to use some code and not external commands.

Comment: I mentioned 2 lines, because I thought it would be very similar to MD5 hashing or something. like $newstring = md5("test");

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than one line of code per language for that.

For ASP you can use a component called CAPICOM that is included with Windows, for PHP the encryption functions is among all other functions. The gotcha I remember from doing this is that the input to capicom is sent as unicode per default. Your best bet is probably to convert the unicode to ascii or something when you get it back from the decryption function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [`str_rot13()`](http://php.net/str-rot13)! ;-)